# Compute the derivative of $f (x) := Ax$ w.r.t. matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, matrix-calculus

> Let function $f : \Bbb R^{3 \times 2} \to \Bbb R^3$ be defined by $f(A) := Ax$. Compute the derivative of $f$ with respect to $A$.

---

I would like to check if my computation is correct. Is it?

[image]

Comment: You need a $3$-dimensional matrix to store all the partial derivatives.

Comment: but why ? is it not depending on the notation ? i did it like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMPhPwmcixM&list=PLhcN-s3_Z7-YS6ltpJhjwqvHO1TYDbiZv&index=4  min 2:03

Comment: Why don't you compute the gradients of the entries of $f$?

Comment: Your notation is unfortunate, IMHO.  Usually, the first letters of the alphabet denote that which is know whereas the last letters of the alphabet denote that which is unknown.  $X \mapsto X a$ would have been nicer.

Comment: i know what you mean but i heard in numerator notation you have to transpose the matrix/vector you differenting with?

Comment: i think  it is the denumartor layout , if i transpose my result then i get the numerator layout and my result at the end

Comment: Math students (and I account myself as one) have to learn to walk before we run.  You should break the problem down into steps you can justify, i.e. a partial derivative of one component of the result with respect to one (independent) component of the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the vector-valued function
$$\eqalign{
 f &= Ax \\
}$$
or in index notation
$$\eqalign{
 f_i &= A_{ij}x_j \\
}$$
Find its differential and gradient wrt $A$
$$\eqalign{
 df_i &= dA_{ij}\,x_j \\\\
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial A_{km}}
  &= \left(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{km}}\right)\,x_j \\
  &= \big(\delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jm}\big) \,x_j \\
  &= \delta_{ik}\,x_m \\
}$$
Note that the result is a third-order tensor.

[Vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) can be used to flatten the gradient into a matrix
$$\eqalign{
df \;&= \Big(I\;dA\;x\Big) \\
   \;&= \Big(x^T\otimes I\Big)\;{\rm vec}(dA) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(A)}
     &= \Big(x^T\otimes I\Big) \\\\
}$$